# Bug with JTextField: Auto resizes if string is large

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager

I have this undecorated JFrame, and I decided to compress the size of these JTextFields to make the design compact.

[image]

The issue is, if a string larger than the text field's length is input by the Browse button in the "Album art" textfield, this happens:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Seems problem with `LayoutManager`, which do you use? Post [MCVE](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Maybe if you use `textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));` .

Comment: @BattleHamster See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: Did not know, sorry for the bad advice.

Comment: Ehh, I use Free Layout. Please help me with respect to NetBeans IDE 8.0-since it has an XML-based drag and drop GUI builder, on which I built my application, it does not allow me to create textfields by code.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what layout manager you are using but I would suggest you try creating your text fields with code like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

The number will give the text field a preferred size so is should not grow as data is entered.

Comment: I use NetBeans IDE 8.0. It does not allow me to do things like create textfields with code because of it's drag-and-drop GUI builder.

Comment: So don't use the IDE. It is always better to learn how to use Java instead of letting the IDE do it for you. Then you don't have problems like this. Also what happens if you change IDE's then you need to learn the IDE all over.

Comment: If I used code instead of an IDE, I wouldn't have been able to design the JFrame the way I designed it. And, I tell you, letting the SDK do such complex JFrame coding and focusing on the required code is pure nirvana. :)